# Splitting up raster values in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, splitting

Is it possible to split up the individual values of a raster to make each value become a different layer?

I am aiming to create an animated map with TimeManager. However, the data I need for each layer of the animated map is within one raster.

The raster is split into 16 values from 2000-2016. Is there a way to take out each value to create a new layer?

Here is a picture of the raster for more clarity.

[image: Here is a picture of the raster for more clarity.]

Comment: Those this raster have several bands or has each pixel a value which corresponds to the year?

Comment: @LaughU Does my picture help your question? Sorry quite new to this and not entirely sure what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For TimeManager, you need a vector, i think :

**Solution 1 :  vectorisation**

If your raster is in integer format :

- use the polygonize tool
- animate on your value field.

[image: polygonize]

To answer your title question :

**Solution 2 : raster reclassification**

- Use a Raster Calculator expression ("MyRaster@1 = 1", then "MyRaster@1 = 2",...)to get a reclassified raster for each year (every pixel that answer the logicial condition is equal to 1 and the others are equal to 0 or are null)
- Create 16 new raster with that.
- put it in display and color it with a 1 = color style

[image: value = 1]

**Solution 3 : duplicate and style**

- just duplicate your raster 16 times (right click/duplicate)
- on the first layer (set all colors to transparent (0% opacity) except the year color
- copy paste style and just change color 2 to full opacity and 1 to 0%.
- do the same for all layers

[image: styling]

Comment: @amd I added another solution if you need vector to animate :)